# Back to the same day name one year ago

Tags: javascript, date

I need to find dinamically given today's date one year ago the same day.

So if today is Monday i need to find the equivalent to today's Monday but one year ago.

Like `03/03/2017` (Friday) would find me `04/03/2017` (Friday).
`16/02/2017` (Thursday) would find me `18/02/2017` (Thursday) and so on.

What I am really interested is in finding the day more than the digits.
I tried the following:

```
 Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
        var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
        dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
        return dat;
    }
    var dateObj = new Date();

    var wanted= dateObj.addDays(-365 + 1);
```

But of course `wanted` has to change dinamically so this doesn't work.
Next I tried finding out the number in the year of that specific Friday in 2017 and then finding that same number in 2017 trying to somehow adapt
[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562173/calculate-number-of-specific-weekdays-between-dates)
But in this case it only counts the number of fridays not the number and I couldn't get it to work.
Maybe the best way would be to be guided by the number of the week and not just the closest Friday to the same number of the date.
Is there any way to do this using only JavaScript (without libraries like Moment.js)

Comment: @NagyNick though its same, tags are totally different

Comment: and what do you consider to be a "same day"? You can say it needs to be i.e. 15th Wednesday in a year, or you want a "closest" wednesday on today's date last year?

Comment: @Mirko Vukušić I guess I could use the number of the week as a guide. Otherwise It would be too complicated

Comment: @Lima9 You should correct the typos. They might confuse someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Take number of years +/- to go backward/forward.
- Use `date.setFullYear` to update date.
- Now check difference between day of both dates.
- Add this difference to date and return it

```js
function getSameDayOfYear(date, yearsToAdd){
  date = typeof(date) === "string" ? new Date(date) : date;
  var retDate = new Date(+date);
  retDate.setFullYear(retDate.getFullYear() + yearsToAdd);
  
  var diff = date.getDay() - retDate.getDay();
  retDate.setDate(retDate.getDate() + diff);
  console.log(retDate.toLocaleDateString())
  return retDate;
}

getSameDayOfYear("03/03/2017", -1)
getSameDayOfYear("02/16/2017", -1)

getSameDayOfYear("03/03/2017", -2)
```

---

As correctly pointed out by @brieucdlf, `setYear` has been deprecated. Its better to use `setFullYear`

Reference: [setYear - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your approach is very interesting!

Comment: setDate is deprecated. Use setFullYear instead. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear

Comment: @brieucdlf Thanks for highlighting. This is a 5 year old answer, so I'll update it with newer version

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight problem in Rajesh's code.  It will go backward 5 or 6 days when it would be "closer" to go forward 1 or 2 instead.

Here is a simple fix:

```
function getSameDayOfYear(date, yearsToAdd){
  date = typeof(date) === "string" ? new Date(date) : date;
  var retDate = new Date(+date);
  retDate.setYear(retDate.getFullYear() + yearsToAdd);
  
  var diff = date.getDay() - retDate.getDay();
  if(diff < -4){
    diff = diff + 7; //go forward instead of backward
  }

  retDate.setDate(retDate.getDate() + diff);
  console.log(retDate.toLocaleDateString())
  return retDate;
}
```