# How to count the number of wednesdays between two given dates in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, datetime

Trying to write a function in Typescript that returns the number of Wednesdays between 2 given dates and I'm stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate number of specific weekdays between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562173/calculate-number-of-specific-weekdays-between-dates)

Answer (score 0):

If you're handling dates, I would advise you to use a library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/).

With luxon you can do it the following way :

```
const start = DateTime.fromObject({ year: 2012, month: 10, day: 1 });
const end = DateTime.fromObject({ year: 2020, month: 5, day: 6 });

const interval = Interval.fromDateTimes(start, end);
const subIntervals = interval.splitBy({ days: 1 });
const wednesday = subIntervals.reduce((wednesdays, subInt) => {
  const d = subInt.start;
  return d.weekday == 3 ? wednesdays + 1 : wednesdays;
}, 0);
```